# If I remove Apple Loops, will reinstalling Garage Band from the App Store later restore them?

Tags: mac-appstore, ilife

I'm attempting to save some space on my new Mac, which had iLife preinstalled. I can confidently delete GarageBand and iMovie for now, since I can easily reinstall them later from the App Store should I need them. However, I'm trepidatious about removing their associated data (which are quite hefty) from `/Library/Application Support/GarageBand` and `/Library/Audio/Apple Loops`. Since these are outside the .app, I'm worried that they won't be included along with the App Store bundles. Does anyone know for sure one way or another?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just zip them (The Unarchiver is nice) and store them in /Users/Shared until it's clear whether you need them again.

I've always used Shared for folders of Copies, Archives, Removed items, all zipped. Very handy.

Comment: Since the goal is to clear up disk space I will definitely be archiving and storing them externally - to be on the safe side. I'm sure I'll be able to answer this question after I've gone through it but I thought I'd ask if anyone had a definitive answer :)